# Langchain, SQL and few shot

Tags: langchain, google-cloud-vertex-ai, huggingface, large-language-model, py-langchain

I'm using SQLDatabaseChain to translate natural language questions into SQL.
I'm using VertexAI, and added few shot examples, embedded them into a vectorDB and then used FewShotPromptTemplate.

I understand that by using this approach, each time the LLM retrieve the closest semantically example (if exists).
When trying to just copy some of the examples directly to the prompt I get improved results.
I wonder why; when should I use which approach for few shot / which preferred.